# load fragment in ViewPager only when its selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs.

I'm loading big data in every fragments.

The app load every fragments but I want to load fragment only when its selected.

How can I do that? I have no idea. 
I'm waiting for your help. Thank you

my code:

```
public class Fragments extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "1");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "2");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If no one has given you a good answer I know this is 5 years later, but anyone reading this. I'm actually having the opposite problem. I need to load all tabs at the same time. What is happening to me now is only one tab is loading at a time. I need to use this adapter for viewpager2 with tablayout so that I can disable the viewpager swiping left to right for my specific usecase.

Here is my code:

**WARNING CODE IS IN KOTLIN NOT JAVA**

```
class RecipeTabAdapter internal constructor(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

val fragmentsList: ArrayList<Fragment> = arrayListOf()

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentsList.add(fragment)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragmentsList.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    when (position) {
        position -> fragmentsList[position]
        position -> fragmentsList[position]
    }
    return fragmentsList[position]
}
```

}

Comment: Well thanks bro you helped me a lot so in this case I know I am late as well, but your adapter is wonderful just change your constructor from:

`class RecipeTabAdapter internal constructor(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle)`  

to →

`class RecipeTabAdapter internal constructor (fragment:Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)`  

So that would help you on your matter to load all fragments at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable the offscreen page limit?

No. It is already set to the minimum possible value: one page to each side of the viewed page. This is necessary to have the animation effects work -- you see parts of two fragments (original and new) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
OncreateView(){

//.... dont initialize your view here

if(isMenuVisible()) { // menu should be visible if current fragment is visible right now
            setUserVisibleHint(true); // manually set value to true
        }

}
```

in

```
 oncreate(){

setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

Finally there is method called setuservisiblehint() which is only called when the fragment is visible to the user this is the only method where you shud initialize all your views.

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if(isVisibleToUser && v != null) {

              // initialize your view here and call you fetch_data_function()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution and it works as expected. In all of your child fragments create a `boolean` variable:

```
private boolean loadFragmentExecuted = false;
```

in the child fragments create a generic method called `loadFragment` and move all of the logic you added in `onCreateView` to that method:

```
public void loadFragment()
{
    if(!loadFragmentExecuted)
    {
        //Add your logic to manipulate the UI or load data etc...
        loadFragmentExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

in your pageview logic create the fragments dynamically like:

```
//add the fragment
String fragmentName = "com.something." + fragmentId;

//check if the class exists
try
{
    Class myFragmentClass = Class.forName(fragmentName);
    Fragment myFragment = (Fragment) myFragmentClass.newInstance();
    mFragments.add(myFragment);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InstantiationException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then set your pager adapter and attach a tablayout with it:

```
//set our pager adapter that contains different fragments
mPagerAdapter = new BasePagerAdapter(mFragmentManager, mFragments);

//link the adapter to the viewpager
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

//cache fragments
int limit = (mPagerAdapter.getCount() > 0 ? mPagerAdapter.getCount() : 1);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);

//add the page listner to the viewPager and link it to the tabLayout
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

//on tab selected select current viewpager item
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        //get fragment for the selected tab
        Fragment f = mPagerAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition());

        //load the content of the fragment
        try
        {
            Class c = f.getClass();
            Method loadFragment = c.getMethod("loadFragment");
            loadFragment.invoke(f);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e){}
        catch (InvocationTargetException e){}
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e){}
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution that does not require subclassing, and it's easy to introduce into existing projects. It uses the child fragment mechanism.

The basic idea is to replace your content fragment with an almost empty fragment, and add your content fragment as a child fragment when it is really visible to the user

The gist of the code is like this

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    boolean hasFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) != null;
    if (hasFragment) {
        return;
    }

    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        addFragment("onViewCreated");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        addFragment("onResume");
    }
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        addFragment("setUserVisibleHint");
    }
}



private void addFragment(String cause) {
    if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) == null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .add(R.id.container, createFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

Check out my full solution here, which also contains a progressbar, and the option to automatically start loading of background fragments with a specified delay: [Lazy Load Fragment](https://github.com/ssynhtn/lazyloadfragment)

Comment: This won't work. Since onResume already been called and isVisibleToUser only true once it visible to user so this condition won't be satisfied and hence it's not a solution.